# Is there an idiom equivalent to / similar to "gut feeling"?

Tags: word-requests, english-to-japanese, idioms, metaphor

Is there an expression or metaphor similar to "gut feeling", as a metaphor for one's intuition or instinctive feeling about something?

Comment: Does https://eow.alc.co.jp/sp/search.html?q=gut%20feeling&pg=1 answer your question?

Comment: Among the contents of the above link, I would vote for the "nantonaku".

Answer (score 3):

There is the idiom 「虫{むし}の知{し}らせ」 that is often found in bilingual dictionaries as one of the definitions for "gut feeling".

IMHO, however, that is closer to "**premonition**" in meaning and feeling than to "gut feeling".

Regular, non-idiom words such as 「直感{ちょっかん}」 and 「第六感{だいろっかん}」 would be closer to "gut feeling" in nuance than 「虫の知らせ」 is.